# How to know what program created this interface/route?

Tags: networking

I found some suspicious interface that I  never heard of

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp9s0
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 virbr0
172.30.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 ztwfulpfjl
172.30.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     450    0        0 ztwfulpfjl
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 enp9s0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
240.1.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 docker0
```

enp9s0 is the LAN

virbr0 probably virtualbox?

docker0 and lxcbr0 looks obvious docker and lxc.

but wtf is `ztwfulpfjl`?

the ifconfig output:

```
ztwfulpfjl: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 2800
        inet 172.30.28.200  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.30.255.255
        inet6 fe80::98dd:e0ff:fe76:e40c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9a:dd:e0:76:e4:0c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23967  bytes 4675018 (4.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

how to know which program created this, or maybe just to be safe, how to remove this?

possible stuff was some firewall saffing or something I installed in the past, or cloudflare warp, or vmware, or maybe one of my past company's vpn: cisco or globalprotect vpn?

Comment: Take networking down, so all the routes disappear, bring networking up.

Comment: `nethogs` can show you what program is using the interface